# Problems when running CompletableFuture methods with java 8

Tags: java, spring-boot, asynchronous, completable-future, spring-async

I have a spring boot application, I've generated the application with jhispter, I have a spring service that has a scheduled method as below:

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 0/2 * * * *")
private void checkStatusRouters() {

    if(!IS_JOB_RUNNING){
        IS_JOB_RUNNING =true;
        log.info("[JOB-MONITOR] - Initializing scan", Instant.now());
        List<MicroTikRouter> routers = routerService.findAllEntities();
        log.info("Roteadores encontrados: {}",routers.size());
        for (MicroTikRouter router : routers) {
            try {
                log.info("Iniciando roteador : {}", router.getDescription());
                CompletableFuture<Boolean> check =  routerService.checkRouterStatusAsync(router);
                check.exceptionally(exception -> {
                    //HandleException
                });
            }
            catch(Exception ex){
                //Handle
            }
        }
}   }
```

This method calls many times the `routerService.checkRouterStatusAsync()` that is described below. (I dont need to wait the result of this method  )

```
@Async
public CompletableFuture<Boolean> checkRouterStatusAsync(MicroTikRouter router) throws  ApiConnectionException,ApiCommandException,Exception {

    //neither this log is appearing
    log.info("Request print router {} : with ip/dns  {} ",router.getCode(),router.getIp());

    //make many things  

    return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(true);
}
```

The strange thing is that nothing on the method `checkRouterStatusAsync` is appearing on the log.

That  is happening only on my production server, locally it works. On both sides (locally and in production), I have Java 8 installed.

I run my application using the command `java -jar {myPackage}.war`.

Anyone can help me?

Comment: Is it a typo that you don't set `IS_JOB_RUNNING` to false in your question?

Comment: the code:        if(!IS_JOB_RUNNING){  IS_JOB_RUNNING =true;   has a race condition. It must be put into critical section.

Comment: Are the other log lines printed? How is your executor configured for Spring Async?

Comment: @DidierL is with spring default